# asp.net MVC EF 6 Identity only allowed to select 'lower' roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I have these roles setup within identity and one role is assigned per user

```
00 - Super Admin
10 - Admin
20 - Staff Manager
30 - Staff
40 - User Manager
50 - User
```

The aim is to allow a user to change the role of other users below (not equal to) their own user role

so if I could get the first two chars from the `Name` of the role added to the current user e.g. 30 then the choice of roles that could be applied to other users would be > 30

to get the user state of the current user

```
var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
var currentUserRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(currentUser);
```

Then something like below that get all the roles, with 'WHERE' clause, or following if statement, first two chars > current users first two chars

```
var allRoles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
```

Does anyone know of a way that this could be done, or if there is a better idea?

Many Thanks

**EDIT:**

Ok, I now have this hardcoded to a `SelectList` in the view, select roles `> 30` which is working

```
ViewBag.allRoles = _roleManager.Roles.Where(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.Name.Remove(2)) > 30).Select(a => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = a.Id.ToString(),
    Text = a.Name.Remove(0, 5).ToString(),
}).ToList();
```

just need to get the current user role name to a string?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to sort it

```
var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

var currentUserRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(currentUser);

int currentUserRoleLevel = int.Parse(currentUserRole[0].Remove(2));

ViewBag.allRoles = _roleManager.Roles.Where(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.Name.Remove(2)) > currentUserRoleLevel).Select(a => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = a.Id.ToString(),
    Text = a.Name.Remove(0, 5).ToString(),
}).ToList();
```

The question still stands, is there a better way?